# Golang program closes file before writing is finished

Tags: go, writer

I have implemented a custom Write interface for my cloud program.
My problem so far is that after i am done copying files to my writer and closed the Writer, the writer still has a few Writes to do(usually maybe 4 writes about 4096 bytes each). The last Write is usually less than 4096.

This has not happened yet but i know it is a probability of 1/4096 that the last Write is 4096 bytes and my program won't terminate.

I am using this for a zipping program and io.EOF is not effective as every write chunk has one, also checking if writer is closed comes too early while there are still some writes to do.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

***EDIT*****
I ended up implementing a more Robust Write(), Flush() and Close() method.Now everything is good if i use defer Close() but i still get the same problem if i manually call Close() at the end

Comment: I don't understand, how do you not know if you've written the data yet? If you have EOF on every chunk you're doing something wrong.

Comment: So i open a file, copy some bytes to it and close it . This part works. The Underlying"Writer" usually takes time to catch up -- i guess from writing chunks. So i get  a situation where file is closed but the underlying writer is almost finished catching up.

Comment: A normal writer would block on Close until it completes all buffered writes. I don't know what your underlying Writer is, but it doesn't sound like it works correctly.

Comment: My writer is simple and just writes p bytes to the underlying buffer. If my buffer gets to 5MB, i do operation 1, if it does not - i do operation 2. I also need to know when to finish operation 1. Usually that is where i check if it is closed. I will look into blocking.

Comment: Yes, you need some way of communicating that the write's haven't completed. A blocking Close method and/or a Flush method are common, but you haven't shown any implementation that is causing the problem, so it's hard to suggest a solution.

Comment: I am actually re-writing parts of my favourite python library in Go. I just now noticed that they implemented Write, Flush and Close. If you can put your last suggestion as an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

since you have full control on the writer, you could use a [waitgroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)
to wait in your `main` for all goroutines to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by implementing a more robust `Close()` function. I also used `defer Close()` to make sure that Golang handled all the Goroutines internally.